# Change color of row based on value of a column in the row

Tags: asp.net, jquery, vb.net, gridview

I have an sqldatasource that loads, data from my server and puts it in a datagrid.

I have a Column named clnumber that has, the numbers 1,2,3

What I want is that each row have a different color depending on which number is in that datarow column

THIS IS THE CODE I USED

```
 $(document).ready(function () {

    $("#<%=GridView1.UniqueID%> tr").each(function () {

        var number = $(this).children('td:eq(6)').text();

        if (number == 'OK') {
            $(this).children('td').css({ "background-color": "lightgreen" });

        }
    })
});
```

Comment: One glaring issue with that snippet of jQuery is that 'Gridview1' doesn't actually refer to anything. Now, '#Gridview1' or '.Gridview1' might actually work. See my new post below with a jQuery solution to this problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Granted you've given your gridview a css class called 'myGridView' you could do the following:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('.myGridView tr').each(function () {

        var number = $(this).children('td:eq(1)').text();

        if (number == '1') {
            $(this).children('td').css('background', 'red');
        }
    })
});
```

where 'td:eq(1)' refers to the second cell in a row. This of course will depend on what cell in your row contains this magic number.

I'm certain it's not the most elegant use of jQuery, but you could refactor it as you wish

Comment: for somereason it isnt working should it be .gridview1 if my gridview name is gridview1 and does it make a difference if i already have a stylesheet.

Comment: If you have a stylesheet already, it might make a difference, though it is unlikely since what i've posted here will render inline css (via the style attribute of the cell's tag) which should take precedence over your stylesheet. Also note that i've assumed the gridview in my example has a css class named 'myGridView'. If you're trying to use the grid view's ID, i suspect it won't work since ASP.NET will render a different ID in the HTML output. Giving the grid view a CSS class name will overcome this problem.

Comment: it worked perfectly thanks the only problem is when i postback or update the panel the grid is in it goes back to normal : /

Answer (score 1):

Based on the number how?
First row white, second grey?

```
if(rownumber%2 == 0) //white
else //grey
```

or the other way around actually.

Comment: that will do it autmatically for every row in the grid?

Comment: Put it in the GridView_RowDataBound event or else if your GridView has Paging it will only be applied for whatever rows that was present at the time the code was run.

Comment: Yes. any number evenly divided by two will be white, the others will be grey.

Comment: hmm could you adapt the method, for example if i want any row with the letter A,B,C. I am going to need this for many things

Comment: How do you mean? You are going to use 'A','B' and 'C' instead of row numbers and use different colors for these? In that case i would just go with a static dictionary<char, color> or something.

Answer (score 1):

If the number that dictates which color should be used is actually generated in the HTML output, why not use javascript?

Comment: thats what many people said online but i am not familiar with javascript, some said even jquery was a possibility

Comment: Yes, jQuery is what I would use. Reference jQuery in the page's HEAD using a SCRIPT tag, then simply iterate over each row, examine each row and the particular cell that holds this number in that row, and write a small function that will set the background color for the row using CSS. I'm sorry, but this is a much simpler approach than messing around with the event handlers for the data grid to pull off something that is purely a layout/CSS issue.

Comment: I tryed using jquery code i will post above and it didn't work

Answer (score 1):

You can use similar to this:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Updates the row fore colour to show the line type
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="sender">object</param>
    /// <param name="e">args</param>
    protected void gvLineValues_RowDataBound( object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e )
    {
        try
        {
            //Format the row
            this.FormatRow( e );
        }
        catch ( Exception ex )
        {
            ErrorLogging.LogError( ex );
        }
    }

  /// <summary>
        /// Formats a gridview row
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="e">Gridview event args</param>
        private void FormatRow( GridViewRowEventArgs e )
        {
            try
            {
                //Change the forecolor of the row
                if ( e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow )
                {
                    OrderLine oOrderLine = e.Row.DataItem as OrderLine;

                    if ( oOrderLine != null )
                    {
                        e.Row.ForeColor = oOrderLine.ForeColour;


                                //Check the line is over budget
                                if ( oOrderLine.OverBudget )
                                {
                                    e.Row.BackColor = ColourManager.OverBudgetItemBackColour;
                                    e.Row.ToolTip = String.Format( "Item over {0} and awaiting your approval", GlobalizationManager.Budget );
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    e.Row.BackColor = ColourManager.WithinBudgetItemBackColour;
                                    e.Row.ToolTip = "Item awaiting your approval";
                                }
                            }
                        }

                        //Change the back colour of the row if its a deleted row
                        if ( oOrderLine.Deleted )
                        {
                            e.Row.Font.Strikeout = true;
                            e.Row.ToolTip = "This line has been deleted";
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            catch ( Exception )
            {
                throw;
            }
        }
```

you could do something like

```
switch ( DataItem.ColorNumber )
{
case 1:

e.row.backcolor = Color.blue;

break;

case 2:

e.row.backcolor = Color.red;

break;

case 3:

e.row.backcolor = Color.white;

break;

}
```

Comment: thanks for your help this will probably be the method i used, unless i can do it with javascript